# Implementing my own Fragment as a DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I was using alert dialog, I could add a "cancel" button using:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(getActivity());
builder.setTitle("Students").setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
    // if this button is clicked, just close
    // the dialog box and do nothing
    dialog.cancel();
  }
});;
```

Now  I'm implementing my own fragment. How can I set the same cancel button?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply override `DialogFragment`'s `onCreateDialog()` method:

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(getActivity());
builder.setTitle("Students").setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
    // if this button is clicked, just close
    // the dialog box and do nothing
    dialog.cancel();
  }
});;
        return builder.create();
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this look helpful but i faced a problem.I added the function you suggested and i got an exception:requestFeature() must be called before adding content.